# How to escape double quotes in a JSON in Java dynamically

Tags: java, json, jackson, escaping

How to escape double quotes inside a JSON given the data in the JSON will be obtained dynamically in Java.

Example:

```json
{
    "key": "I ask silly questions on "https://www.stackoverflow.com". "
}
```

In this case, the value in the JSON is populated from dynamically let's say from a user input.

I have tried StringEscapeUtils provided by apache-commons-lang (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html), but this escapes the entire JSON where as the double quotes inside the JSON needs to escape again.

Possible solution will be to use regex and filter out the value in JSON and escape once before escaping the overall JSON.

But, is there any JAR to escape the inner contents of a JSON?

Comment: Could you not just do a `String.replaceAll("\"", "\\"");`.

Comment: Yes, I can. But I was searching for a JAR that would do this. Let's say I input a string which is a user's input in my case. The JAR should check whether the input has a JSON and should escape the double quotes inside the value in the matched JSON. I would not want to escape all the double quotes from the users input.

Comment: Why use an external library and make your application heavier and slower when you can code it yourself in a 1-line method? This is the best solution for your problem I think. If a user enters `I am a new "user"` and you use @Adam 's solution you will end with `I am a new \"user\"` and the String will be escaped correctly

Comment: Well I'm using apache-commons,Jackson and Gson for other purposes. Just wanted to know if there is a library that does this which all these above libraries, from my knowledge, does not perform it in one go.

Comment: You could find a library for this specific use case if you're lucky. But it's much easier to just write it yourself as @VictorCalatramas suggested as it's a trivial solution. if you want to only escape quotes around URLs that's a bit more involved as you'll need to do some regex matching. But still using a library for this is likely to take you more time than just implementing it yourself.

Comment: You aren't going to find a library that does this. Based on what you are saying, this is likely a buggy implementation. If the user input the following text `{ "key": "I ask silly questions on "https://www.stackoverflow.com". "}`; it's not even a valid json to begin, there is not point trying to deserialize it. 

The input should be `{ "key": "I ask silly questions on \"https://www.stackoverflow.com\". "}`. At least this is what I think based on the current wording in the question.

Comment: If you have such a string it is not JSON. You need to provide some minimal code how do you get this so-called-JSON  and what is your problem when converting it to a real JSON.

Answer (score 0):

If doing json processing in java I would use [Jackson databind](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind) and let it handle json generation. You will probably want to turn some knobs eventually, but simplest possible usage will probably do for this use case:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(singletonMap("key", "I ask silly questions..."));
```